# Time series: daily data and daily data without weekends

Tags: time-series, dataset

I've got a daily data set on Bitcoin's price. Trading continues in the weekends, hence there is price data in the weekends as well.

On the other hand, i've got another daily data set. This set does not have data for the weekends.

I want to make a time series regression with the two sets but what should i do with the weekends? Should I replace the empty weekends with the average? Then, missing values will just be replaced by the average.

Edit:
Im going to regress dataset X on the price of BTC. Thus BTC is the dependent variable.
Dataset X: no weekend data, workweeks=daily data
BTC: daily data on the price, also weekends.

Comment: Imputing OFR index doesn't make a sense, some of its constituents are not observed on weekends. Outside trading hours you can't assume much about the behavior of the indicators. Also, regressing that index on BTC is probably pointless due to severe endogeneity issues: if anything the relationship must be the other way around

Comment: I know that some of its components are not observed on weekends. Therefore my question: how should I handle the fact there are no values for the weekends regarding the independent variable? Usual tests for endogeneity will be performed. Just drawing upon earlier research...

Comment: skip the weekends as if they never existed, if you're running contemporaneous regression; alternatively, add a dummy variable for day of week, pre-/after holidays etc. in time series you could do a little more than that

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. Do you perhaps have a document/ paper/ book suggestion about this specific subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming you produce two models, one for predicting Bitcoin (BTC), one for predicting the other while always using both as inputs:*

- For predicting BTC (imputing input only): Fill the last value from the work-week (e.g. Friday) as value for the weekend.
- For predicting the other (imputing input and output): You can do the same as above (will introduce a slight bias to predict values that appear on Fridays). Or you can consider discarding weekend BTC data and just treat the problem as time series without weekend.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. Should be more specific about my question. Im going to regress dataset X on the price of BTC. Thus BTC is the dependent variable. Regarding your first option: why would I use last value from the work week and not use the average? What is the benefit and logic of your suggestion? Regarding your second point: if im going to predict BTC, would your suggestion still be useful? Why not?

Comment: Ah, in that case you should treat it as if the weekends didn't exist, as @Aksakal suggested in his comment. The second point is not relevant anymore after your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to ask a question but I don't have enough rep to comment. Do you have to use this dataset?

https://www.investing.com/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data

This dataset contains all close prices including weekends (you can adjust the amount of time but it does only have data going back to 2012 if that's a concern).

If not you should use imputation, in R there are many packages to do this, careful which one you choose though because your data is almost certainly autocorrelated. While I have not used it myself, the 'imputets' package is supposedly a strong choice for imputing the values in R, also consider 'amelia' (uses bootstraping, which would be better and less biased).  You could take a moving average to impute the data yourself if you prefer, but I think if you can use a dataset that has the actual values you should, what if volatility spikes on weekends, or conversely, there's less vol on the weekends because major firms that trade in the currency may not be actively trading? If you can't find a full dataset, a time series specific imputation would be most efficient and least biased, compared to an average.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the answer. Yes i'm ging to use the data set you posted. BTC exchange rate data will be the dependent variable. The other data set will be a volatility index (OFR Financial stress index). The latter contains only daily data of workweeks and no weekend data. Do you have a link to a document on how to do time specific imputation for the weekends? I prefer that over imputing the average if that leads to somewhat biased data...

Comment: This is from the developers of the 'imputets' package. It doesn't go very deep into proofs but explains the implications of using general imputation methods on time dependent data.
 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/vignettes/imputeTS-Time-Series-Missing-Value-Imputation-in-R.pdf

Comment: @Robbert forgot to tag you, answer above^.

Also, here is the link to the codebook for the package which explains a little more.  It looks simple enough to use, and I tried it out with a couple test of the test datasets.  You'll need to make spaces in your OFR stress index data for the weekend, denote the missing values "NA" and then impute the values using one of the functions (the paper in my first comment suggest `na.kalman` for larger datasets, you can read into it more).